# validate negative number in jquery with one decimal place

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I want to validate text field using jauery in the following manner:

**1. Text field take only 0-9 with only one decimal place;and**

**2. If amount enter in not in negative, put the negative symbol at the
    begging of digits entered!**

```
$('[name="pm"]').keyup(function() {

    //?

 });
```

Comment: This isn't a jQuery thing, it's a JavaScript thing. I've added the tag for you.

Comment: No offense but this looks like "give me the codes" type of a question. You should consider telling us what you tried first.

Answer (score 6):

You can validate the string via a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
if (this.value.match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d){0,1}$/)) {
    // It's valid
}
```

Or more jQuery-ish (and the above doesn't support `textarea` reliably, just `input`):

```
if ($(this).val().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d){0,1}$/)) {
    // It's valid
}
```

(E.g., `this.value` => `$(this).val()`.)

Breaking the regex down:

- `^` - Match start of string
- `-?` - A single optional `-` character
- `\d+` - One or more digits (0-9)
- `(?:...)` - A non-capturing grouping, containing:

  - `\.\d` - At most one `.` followed by a single digit
- `{0,1}` - Allow the non-capturing grouping zero or one time
- `$` - Match end of string

Note that the above rejects `-.1`. If you want to accept it, it gets more complex, but the link above should help.

[Gratuitous live example](http://jsbin.com/omupay) | [source](http://jsbin.com/omupay/edit)

Comment: I want to validate it on key up event, as I stated above. When I press negative symbol - at start , it not taking. but my requirement is ...... second point of the post!(major)

Comment: Then you can do this test, but remove the `-?` part, and then check `$(this).val().indexOf('-') == 0` (if it starts with `-`) if not, say `var val = $(this).val()` and then `$(this).val("-" + val)` (Aargh why do I always forget: @ShahidGhafoor)

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor: Strongly recommend against validating on keyup, or at least not in any intrusive way. In your particular case, you can readily avoid an unnecessary "invalid" flag by checking for `this.value !== "-"` first, since your string is quite simple. E.g., `if (this.value !== "-") { /* ...do validation... */ }`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code.

```
$('[name="pm"]').keyup(function() {
   if($(this).val().indexOf('-') != 0){ 
      var val = $(this).val();
      $(this).val("-" + val);
   }
});
```

In case it does not work, replace this with $('[name="pm"]')

Comment: Nice! but there are two problems! 1)It taking more than one negative symbol, I just required only one - symbol at start.2)If user enter the amount then negative place at start, at this time, you suggested solution, place - symbol at start even user just click on the text field.

Comment: cope from my above post .....If amount enter in not in negative, put the negative symbol at the begging of digits entered!(IF AMOUNT ENTERED, THEN .....)(IF EMPTY THEN NO NEED OF - SYMBOL) hope I clear the scenario again

Comment: Yes mate, just saw your post.. but i see @t.j.crowder has already answered.

Answer (score 1):

Arrangement and addition for specified solution:

**From @Some_Coder Answer**

1) First Do this

```
http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/
```

**from playmaker answer with modification**

```
$('[name="pm"]').keyup(function() {

   if($(this).val().indexOf('-') != 0){ 
      var val = $(this).val();
      $(this).val("-" + val);
   }


if ($(this).val() == '-') {
            $(this).val('');
        }
});
```

You will get the desire result !

Answer (score 0):

if you use jQuery, than you can use this plugin.

http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

Comment: If amount enter in not in negative, put the negative symbol at the begging of digits entered! what about this?